# Avoid extra parenthesis when writing for comprehensions

Tags: scala

I have this code

```
def doCheck() : Boolean = (for {
    c <- foo.getOption()
    d <- bar.getOption()
    if c == d
} yield true) getOrElse false
```

Every time I write such code, the scala-style (IntelliJ 2017.1) check complains "unnecessary parenthesis" but if I remove the `(` and `)` around the for comprehension then the compiler would throw an error. How can I make both the scala style check and the compiler both happy.

Somehow I feel that the `(` around the for is just code noise.

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732570/a-better-syntax-for-recovery-from-a-for-comprehension